# Checking for duplicates using jQuery and localStorage

Tags: jquery, html

Need to check for duplicates before storing new values in localStorage.

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rowbuck/gaG6k/) that does everything I need except that.

Please feel free to suggest any other ways you see that will help me improve—still learning.

Here's part of the code that's in the fiddle:

```
("button#save").click(function () {
    var id = $("#id").val();


    if (id != "") {
        var text = 'http://' + id + '.tumblr.com';
    } else {
        alert('empty');
        return false
    }

    // UPDATE
    var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blog"));
    if (result == null) result = [];

    result.push({
        id: id,
        tumblr: text
    });
    // SAVE
    localStorage.setItem("blog", JSON.stringify(result));


    // APPEND
    $("#faves").append('<div class="blog"><button class="del" id=' + id + '>x</button><a target="_blank" href=' + text + '>' + imgstem + id + imgstemclose + '</a></div>');


});

// INIT
var blog = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blog"));
var stem = 'http://'
var stemclose = '.tumblr.com';
var imgstem = '<img src="http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/'
var imgstemclose = '.tumblr.com/avatar/48"/>'

//console.log(blog[0].id);

if (blog != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < blog.length; i++) {
        var item = blog[i];
        var text = 'http://' + item.id + '.tumblr.com';
        $("#faves").append('<div class="blog"><button class="del" id=' + item.id + '>x</button><a  href=' + text + '>' + imgstem + item.id + imgstemclose + '</a></div>');

    }
}

$('#faves').on('click', 'button.del', function (e) {

    var id = $(e.target).attr('id');

    // UPDATE
    var blog = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blog"));

    var blog = blog.filter(function (item) {
        return item.id !== id;
    });

    // SAVE
    localStorage.setItem("blog", JSON.stringify(blog));


    // REMOVE
    $(e.target).parent().remove();

});
```

Comment: will you be able to use underscore library

Comment: @ArunPJohny I would prefer to not add any more libraries and keep this lightweight to simply check for duplicate keys. However, if you feel that using underscore would add real value in a refactor, I'd be happy to see it.

Comment: not much... see this with underscore http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KCPA6/1/

Comment: and this without http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KCPA6/2/ ... the search function can be improved though

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks! That fiddle is allowing the duplicates, the one below you posted separately is too. However, the underscore version seems to work. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: see the update http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KCPA6/13/ ... it was a minor bug used `blog` instead of `result` in filter query

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ahh, this one seems to work fine. Thank you!  Now I need to figure out how to clear the input box value on a successful save and make some sort of message when a duplicate is encountered. Then, I need to look more closely at how you did this to further my learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See a very simple implementation

```
$("button#save").click(function () {
    var id = $("#id").val();

    if (id == "") {
        alert('empty');
        return false
    }

    // UPDATE
    var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blog")) || [];

    var loc = result.filter(function (item) {
        return item.id === id;
    });
    if (loc.length) {
        return;
    }

    var text = 'http://' + id + '.tumblr.com';
    result.push({
        id: id,
        tumblr: text
    });
    // SAVE
    localStorage.setItem("blog", JSON.stringify(result));


    // APPEND
    $("#faves").append('<div class="blog"><button class="del" id=' + id + '>x</button><a target="_blank" href=' + text + '>' + imgstem + id + imgstemclose + '</a></div>');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KCPA6/)